# Device-User unique identifier

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.8

Is there a way to get a unique deviceID/userID combination from Windows Phone?
Let me explain: I'd like the unique ID **NOT** to change between app-reinstalls, but change when device ownership is transferred.

There is already a device ID property: `DeviceExtendedProperties.DeviceUniqueId`, but that is unique to a device and does change with ownership transfers.

I guess I need some kind of userId. Is this available?

Comment: You cannot get the user's account on the device. You'll have to ask for it. But then again, The user may have 2 devices and use the same account on them. Maybe use user's phone number but you'll have to ask for it and could use some kind of SMS service to verify it.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud, Is there any way to get an identifier, which changes when the ownership is transferred? I don't actually need the user account

Comment: Not really. Ownership can be transferred by simply selling the phone without even a reset, everything else on the device will stay the same.